# Web Socket Check User State

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, java-websocket, phpwebsocket

I want to check users about they are online or offline . When Internet going to off so internet going to down , i want to change the state of people . How can i do this ?

Like whatsapp , when i Close whatsapp app , my state going to be offline . When i going to chance my internet to shut down , my state going to be offline . When i open activity or screen my state going to Online. How can i check it ? I need send message from my client when Internet going to down.

```
if(!isInternetConnected)
 {
   Socket.down();
 }
```